# How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2}/{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2}/{(n+1)!}$

I know the answer to this question is $e - 1$ from wolfram alpha, but I do not understand how to get there. I know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e,$ but I am not sure how to use it to get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n+1)!} = e-1.$$

Comment: Context seems to be given. They know the answer; they know the summation to use. They just need to write $n^2=(n+1)n-(n+1)+1$. This is something with which experience will help, and which might not be easy for a beginner. Help from someone with experience is worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the diferentiation approach is more standard, here is an elementary method:

\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x+1)!} &= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)!}\frac{x^2}{x(x+1)} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)!}\frac{x}{x+1} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)!}\frac{x+1-1}{x+1} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)!}\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right) \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)!}-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x-1)!(x+1)} \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x!}-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{x}{(x+1)!} \\
&= e-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{x+1-1}{(x+1)!} \\ 
&= e-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{x+1}{(x+1)!}+\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+1)!} \\
&= e-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x!}+\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+1)!} \\
&= e-\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x!}+\sum_{x=2}^\infty\frac{1}{x!} \\
&= e-1
\end{align}

The only we need to know is that $\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{x!}=e$ and to notice that the last equality is due to a telescopic sum. The rest is elementary algebra.

Edit: I know this kind of questions doesn't have to be answered, but it was already answered when I wrote my solution.

Comment: Nice elementary solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to express $n^2$ in a specific form:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(n+1)!}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)n-(n+1)+1}{(n+1)!}\\[10pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)n}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\[10pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\[10pt]
&=\mathrm e-(\mathrm e-1)+\mathrm e-2=\mathrm e-1.
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) The first step is just what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the notation a little,
$e^x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}
$.

Differentiating,
$e^x
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}
$
so
$xe^x
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{nx^{n}}{n!}
$.

Differentiating again,
$(x+1)e^x
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^2x^{n-1}}{n!}
$
so
$x(x+1)e^x
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^2x^{n}}{n!}
$.

Setting $x=1$
will give you
what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much